# How do I make my Yubikey Standard work with Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, udev, cinnamon, yubikey

In another word, I need to allow my Linux account to access my Yubikey Standard (Security Key) by adding a `udev` rule for the device.
**Preamble:**
I was trying to add Yubikey Standard as a Security Key in Google Account's 2FA alongside Google Authenticator. And turns out it doesn't work. Clicking on the help link takes me to the FAQ: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6103543 
*How do I make my Security Key work with Linux?*

> If you are using Linux, you need to allow your Linux account to access
> your Security Key by adding a udev rule for the device. Please refer
> to your Security Key vendor's help page for details.

Couldn't find any help page on yubikey's site, at least one that I understand. Btw, it's a legacy/discounted `Yubikey2` (model name known as `Yubikey Standard`) that is a `non-U2F device`. This is the exact look of the device: 
[image]
<sub>(source: [yubico.com](https://www.yubico.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/YubiKey-Standard-705x603.png))</sub>

---

**OS:** Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit
**Cinnamon Version:** 3.2.7
**Linux Kernel:** 4.4.0-21-generic
**YubiKey Firmware Version:** 2.4.2
**Features Supported:** ✓Yubico OTP, ✓2 Configurations, ✓OATH-HOTP, ✓Static Password, ✓Scan Code Mode, ✓Challenge-Response, ✓Updatable
**Features NOT-Supported:**  ✗Ndef,  ✗Universal 2nd Factor

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a rule allowing some non-root users writing to your key:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d# cat 70-u2f.rules 
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0113|0114|0115|0116|0120"
```

Check your `lsusb` in doubt for vendor and product ID, my key doesn't look exactly like yours, ...

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Using Your U2F YubiKey with Linux](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006449-using-your-u2f-yubikey-with-linux)

From the article:

To set up your Linux system for U2F:

1. If you have a YubiKey NEO or YubiKey NEO-n ensure you have unlocked the U2F mode by following the instructions in the Enabling or Disabling Connection Interfaces article
2. Go to https://github.com/Yubico/libu2f-host/blob/master/70-u2f.rules and download or create a copy of the file named 70-u2f.rules into the Linux directory: /etc/udev/rules.d/ If this file is already there, ensure that the content looks like the one provided on github.com/Yubico (link above).

   Note: If your version of UDEV is lower than 188, use the rules at https://github.com/Yubico/libu2f-host/blob/master/70-old-u2f.rules instead. If you do not known your udev version, you can check by running "sudo udevadm --version" in a Terminal.
3. Save your file, and then reboot your system.
4. Ensure that you are running Google Chrome version 38 or later.
   Starting with Chrome version 39, you will be able to use the YubiKey
   NEO or YubiKey NEO-n in U2F+HID mode

The file referenced has this line:

`# Yubico YubiKey
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0113|0114|0115|0116|0120|0200|0402|0403|0406|0407|0410", TAG+="uaccess"`

Comment: Unfortunately the Yubikey in question is a legacy/discounted Yubikey2 (model name known as Yubikey Standard) that is a non-U2F device. `